# How to self-document required option in a grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

Is there standard way to:

1. Require an option in a grunt task? In other words, I have a grunt task that requires a command-line option. This does not seem the same as configs. this.requiresConfig() doesn't work. I assume that's because "configs" are different than "options".
2. Self-document options for tasks, without putting it directly in the description parameter in registerTask, registerMultiTask. I'd like to be able to see what each task takes as options when I do grunt -h.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm facing the very same problem.